# If Condition error

Tags: android

whenever we execute following code only one statement called all the time which is complete text field. please tell me whats the problem..

```
public  void save_record()
{
    final String name_val  = name.getText().toString();
    final String pass_val  = password.getText().toString();
    final String cpass_val = cpassword.getText().toString();
    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {               
                if(name_val.equals("") || pass_val.equals("") || cpass_val.equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Complete Text Field",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                        if(pass_val!=cpass_val)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "password not Match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            db.insert(name_val, cpass_val);
                            db.close();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "save", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                }        

         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: use pass_val.equals(cpass_val) == false like in the first if statemant

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 if(!pass_val.equals(cpass_val)){

  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "password not Match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 else
 {
  db.insert(name_val, cpass_val);
  db.close();
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "save", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, never use **pass_val!=cpass_val** for String compare.

use

```
    if(!pass_val.equals(cpass_val)){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "password not Match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Then, debug your app to check if some of the three pass texts comes empty.